# How to calculate number of minute step between the time

Tags: javascript, time

I had start time and end time. The minute step is 15 minutes from start time to end time. I want to create a function to calculate the number of minutes step between the start time and end time.

```
function calculateNumberMinuteSteps(start_hour, start_minute, end_hour, end_minute, minute_step){
   // start time 8.15
   // end time 18.30
   // minute_step default 15
}

calculateNumberMinuteSteps(8, 15, 18, 30, 15); // Returns number of minute steps between 8.15am and 6.30pm
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you running into trouble?

Comment: Convert the start and end times to numbers, subtract them, and divide by the step.

Comment: So you want to calculate how many `minute_step` there are (in this case, being `15`) between with start time and end time?

Comment: `// Returns number of minute steps between 8.15am and 6.30pm` - no it doesn't, it returns undefined because you've written zero code

Answer (score 1):

if you return this you will get what you want;

```
   return((end_hour-start_hour)*60 + (end_minute-start_minute))/minute_step;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function calculateNumberMinuteSteps(start_hour, start_minute, end_hour, end_minute, minute_step) {
  const start_seconds = (start_hour * 60 * 60) + (start_minute * 60);
  const end_seconds = (end_hour * 60 * 60) + (end_minute * 60);
  const step_seconds = (minute_step * 60);
  return (end_seconds - start_seconds) / step_seconds;
}

console.log(calculateNumberMinuteSteps(8, 15, 18, 30, 15));
```

Comment: JS is camelCase, and why do all the work for them? :)

Comment: bc im a lonely boi

Comment: that cheered me up, im -2 lonely

Answer (score 0):

It would be very easy to calculate. Just create two dates and the difference would be the value in seconds. Then get the quotient.

```js
function calculateNumberMinuteSteps(start_hour, start_minute, end_hour, end_minute, minute_step){
   // start time 8.15
   // end time 18.30
   // minute_step default 15
   minute_step === undefined?15:minute_step;
   var d1 = new Date("2000-01-01 " + start_hour + ":" + start_minute + ":00"),
       d2 = new Date("2000-01-01 " + end_hour + ":" + end_minute + ":00"),
       seconds =  (d2- d1)/1000, 
       step = Math.floor(seconds/(60*minute_step));
       return step;
}

calculateNumberMinuteSteps(8, 15, 18, 30, 15); // Returns number of minute steps between 8.15am and 6.30pm

console.log(calculateNumberMinuteSteps(8, 15, 18, 30, 15))
```

Answer (score 0):

The below will do exactly what you need

```
function calculateNumberMinuteSteps(start_hour, start_minute, end_hour, end_minute, minute_step){
  var startTime = new Date(0, 0, 0, start_hour, start_minute)
  var endTime = new Date(0, 0, 0, end_hour, end_minute);
  var difference = endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime();
  return steps difference/(minute_step * 60000);
}

var steps = calculateNumberMinuteSteps(8, 15, 18, 30, 15);
```

**[Here is a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/v3g4nxxt/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

`(end_hour + end_minute / 60) - (start_hour + start_minute / 60)` equals total hours as decimal number, multiplied by `60 / minute_step` returns the product of total hours divided by fifteen minute periods.

```js
function calculateNumberMinuteSteps(sh = start_hour, sm = start_minute, eh = end_hour, em = end_minute, ms = minute_step, H = 60) {
   // start time 8.15
   // end time 18.30
   // minute_step default 15
   return ((eh + em / H) - (sh + sm / H)) * H / ms
}

var quarters = calculateNumberMinuteSteps(8, 15, 18, 30, 15); 

console.log(quarters);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple please see below:

```
function calculateNumberMinuteSteps(start_hour, start_minute, end_hour, end_minute, minute_step){
  var startNumber = start_hour * 60 + start_minute;
  var endNumber = end_hour * 60 + end_minute;
  var totalSteps = (endNumber - startNumber) / minute_step;
  console.log(totalSteps);
}

calculateNumberMinuteSteps(8, 15, 18, 30, 15);
```

Answer (score -1):

JS is a camelCase language, btw

```
function calculateNumberMinuteSteps(startTime, endTime, stepSize){
   return (endTime - startTime)/stepSize;
}
```

assuming all units are milliseconds :)